# MySQL: How to solve syntax error on ALTER TABLE statement during change type of column

Tags: mysql

When running

```
ALTER TABLE my_table modify column my_column int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

I've got the error message:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0' at line 1.
```

How can this issue being fixed?

Comment: Works fine for me on `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.20-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`. Please share your exact MySQL version and the structure of the table before your attempt to modify it.

Comment: to test it please create a new testing table and try to use this alter statement for this new table and check if still getting error.

Comment: What client do you use to run this command?

Comment: Just out of couriosity: int(10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE mycolumn my_column INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';
```

Answer (score 3):

`ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...` does not allow renaming the column; this is why the name of the column must be provided only once (the current name).

In order to rename the column (besides other changes you may want to operate on it, like changing its type) you have to use `ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE COLUMN ...` and provide the current **and** the new name of the column.

See the documentation page of the  [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)  statement for more explanation and examples.